# Get specific range with regex within string

Tags: regex

Get specific range with regex within string

**REGEX:**

```
-(.*).......:
```

**DATA**

```
SRV-srvdata-q_SRV_20:DAT
SRV-srvdata-p:DAT
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hoinvap01-q
hoha
```

**GOAL**

```
srvdata-q
srvdata-p
```

Comment: Try `-([^:_]+)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match any 1+ chars from the first hyphen to the first `_` or `:`.

You may use

```
-([^:_]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Go28qH/1)

The `[^:_]+` will match any 1+ chars other than `:` and `_`.